# LINQ won't sum a group with a float? property

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following LINQ expression:

```
pantry = (from p in items
          group p by p.IngredientId into g
          select new PantryItem() { IngredientId = g.Key, Amt = g.Sum(p => p.Amt) });
```

Basically, I'm trying to remove duplicates from an array by summing up their total amounts.  So if I have 2 items of *IngredientId x*, one with *Amt 5* and the other with *Amt 10*, I want a single item of *Ingredient x* with the *Amt 15*.  Easy enough right?

Now, to completely break everything, `Amt` is actually a `float?`, not a `float`.  However, when I `Sum` a group with all `null` amounts, I get `0.0` instead of `null`.

Here's what I want:

```
x - null
x - null
y - 5
y - 10
z - 10
z - null
```

Should convert to:

```
x - null
y - 15
z - 10
```

But instead I get:

```
x - 0.0
y - 15
z - 10
```

Is there a way to re-work my LINQ query to facilitate this?  Hopefully my question is clear enough :)

Comment: Well is `Amt` in `PantryItem` of Nullable type ? I think its not probably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

1. Write your own implementation of `Sum`
2. Check if all values are `null`, then return `null`, otherwise return sum, e.g.:

---

```
pantry = (from p in items
          group p by p.IngredientId into g
          select new PantryItem() 
          { 
              IngredientId = g.Key, 
              Amt = g.Any(p => p.Amt.HasValue) ? g.Sum(p => p.Amt) : null 
          });
```

NOTE: 2<sup>nd</sup> query will enumerate twice.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in one LINQ statement, or should I build an array of the null groups, then build an array of the not null groups, then append them together?

Comment: Oh cool (ignore comment, I wrote that before you updated your answer) - I'll try this out!